# Singleton class of singleton class of BasicObject in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, eigenclass

This is mostly an “academic” one but here it goes:

According to this Ruby eigenclass diagram (slightly edited):

[image: Possibly-wrong Ruby eigenclass diagram]

`BasicObject.singleton_class.singleton_class.superclass` is `Class`.

However, running this on a Ruby interpreter (Ruby v2.5.1), it turns out that `BasicObject.singleton_class.singleton_class.superclass` is `#<Class:Class>` and not `Class`. Therefore, is the diagram lying or am I missing something?

The diagram is from a user I chatted with at Ruby IRC in Freenode. However, it's been quoted multiple times to many other users and it's been treated as the Ruby object model bible.

Comment: `BasicObject.singleton_class.singleton_class.is_a?(Class) #⇒ true` `#Class` is a string representation.

Comment: Your question says `BasicObject.singleton_class.singleton_class` but your diagram says `BasicObject.singleton_class.singleton_class.superclass`. Please clarify.

Comment: @Stefan @mudasobwa You are right. I meant to say `BasicObject.singleton_class.singleton_class.superclass`. I also edited the question. Any clues are more than welcome.

Comment: @kstratis: not sure what confusion is still there after mudasobwa's clarification. It IS a Class.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev According to the diagram `BasicObject.singleton_class.singleton_class.superclass` is simply `Class`. However in reality is the singleton class of `Class` which is `#Class`. It can't be both. Which one is correct and why?

Comment: @kstratis: ah, I see. Well, when a diagram conflicts with reality, the answer to "which is correct" is obvious. :)

Comment: You keep saying `#Class`.  What's your ruby version and/or env where you see this? for me it's `#<Class:Class>`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Right. `#<Class:Class>`  is what I meant. `#Class` was just a shortcut I made up for brevity. Using Ruby v2.5.1 on macOS.

Comment: Indeed, this is confusing. Where is that diagram from?

Comment: Yeah, don't use confusing shortcuts that only you are aware of. We programmers like exactness :)

Comment: It's from a user I chatted with at Ruby IRC in freenode. However it's been quoted multiple times to many other users and it's been treated as the Ruby object model bible... Turns out it's got its flaws...

Comment: I'm betting it _was_ accurate at the time. If only we could find out what ruby version was current at the moment of making the diagram.

Comment: Or who made this (so that we can tweet at them, or something)

Comment: I like your train of thought. This COULD be true. Maybe it was accurate at the time. On the other hand I haven't heard of any object model changes in Ruby in recent years. Anyway to tell you the truth I don't remember. It was months ago. I'll try to ping a moderator at the IRC and will update the post in case of any updates. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Checked a few ruby versions down to 1.9.3. All exhibit the same behaviour. Guess we were reading the wrong bible all this time :)

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of the Ruby interpreter makes perfect sense because:

- When a `Child` class extends a `Parent`, Ruby sets it up so that the singleton class `#<Class:Child>` extends `#<Class:Parent>` as well; and
- `BasicObject.singleton_class` is a subclass of `Class`, so `BasicObject.singleton_class.singleton_class` will be a subclass of `#<Class:Class>`

Verifying the equality:

```
BasicObject.singleton_class.singleton_class.superclass.equal?(Class.singleton_class)
#=> true
```

This leads to the next question – why does `#<Class:BaseObject>` extend `Class` in the first place? Following the rule above, since `BaseObject` has no superclass – that is, `BaseObject.superclass` is `nil` – the logical thing would be for its singleton class to not have a superclass either.

The answer is that `#<Class:BaseObject>` extending `Class` ensures consistency in the inheritance hierarchy when it comes to singleton classes. Take this Ruby object for example:

```
obj = "a string"
```

It is a well-established notion that instead of `obj` being simply an instance of `String`, we can think of it as an (only) instance of its own singleton class, which in turn is a subclass of `String`. That is:

```
obj.class.equal?(obj.singleton_class.superclass)
#=> true
```

It seems only logical that the same should apply to class instances as well. But it does not, because it contradicts the rule mentioned above, where the superclass of a singleton class of a `Child` class is the singleton class of its `Parent` class.

```
class Foo; end

Foo.class
#=> Class

Foo.singleton_class.superclass
#=> #<Class:Object>      <-- not equal to Class!

# because:
Foo.superclass
#=> Object
```

But it is possible to resolve this contradiction by placing `Class` at the top of the singleton class inheritance hierarchy:

```
Foo.singleton_class.superclass
#=> #<Class:Object>

Foo.singleton_class.superclass.superclass
#=> #<Class:BasicObject>

Foo.singleton_class.superclass.superclass.superclass
#=> Class
```

This way, even though `Foo.singleton_class.superclass` is not equal to `Foo.class`, by walking up the inheritance chain, it does get there eventually...